# IntelliJ - Copy Path... -> Absolute Path (control command C) to MacBook Touch Bar

Tags: intellij-idea

Small question regarding IntelliJ please.

On a MacBook, with IntelliJ, Settings -> Preferences -> Appearances & Behavior -> Menus & Toolbars -> Touch Bar -> Default, I added "Copy Path".

However, it is not reflecting in the MacBook Touch Bar. I can add other shortcuts fine, such as Reformat Code, Show History, etc...

Screenshot reflecting the issue (we can clearly see one button is missing)
[image]

[image]

And is this even the shortcut for **Absolute Path**?
How to add **Copy Path... -> Absolute Path (control command C)** to MacBook Touch Bar please?

Thank you

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you show a screenshot of the configuration you have added? Where the focus is at this time when you want to use the action? Make sure you are running IDE under JetBrains Runtime: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879

Comment: Of course, question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `Copy Path...` not `Copy Paths` action.

Comment: Yes! One step closer. so Copy Path... (with the three dots) is not set in the Touch Bar, and working! However, when I press it, it opens the options, "Absolute Path" "File name" etc... I am interested in having the first one in the Touch Bar. But this is very close